# If a continuous function is bounded by $e$ On interior - proof that it is bounded by e on closure

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying the understand this statement . It seems trivial / but thinking about a formal proof - couldn't come up with any unfortunately. Any tips?

Comment: A hint: If $a_n \leq e$ then $\lim a_n\leq e$. Note that the statement is only true if "bounded" means $\leq$. Not true for strict $<$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, consider $f:R\rightarrow R$ defined by $f(x)=x$. Let $A=[0,1]\bigcup \{2\}$, the interior of $A$ is $(0,1)$, $f$ is bounded by $1$ on $(0,1)$ but not by $1$ on the adherence of $A$.